# Change range of bytes by address in pipe

Tags: linux, bash

I've got some binary data that is streaming through a bash pipeline. The data is usually more than 50MB in size.

The existing code looks roughly like this

```
inputprocess | filter1 | filter2 | filter3 > result.txt
```

I know theres bad values at the 30000-30099 bytes after the first filter in the stream. I know what the values should be. I just need to replace the bad bytes with the good ones. There's no change in the data length.

If this was line based I'd use something like:

```
inputprocess | filter1 | sed -e'SOMETHING' | filter2 | filter2 > result.txt
```

However I'm not sure what should go inplace of the `sed` when working with bindary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` is line-oriented and not a natural fit to problems with binary data.  However, `head` and `tail` will work:

```
inputprocess | filter1  | { head -c29999 ; echo -n "replacement" ; tail -c+100 ; } | filter2 | filter3 > result.txt
```

`head -c29999` echos the first 29,999 bytes to stdout.  Then the replacement text is sent to stdout.   Then, `tail -c+100` skips the next 100 bytes of input (the ones that you wanted to replace) and copies the rest to stdout.

This works assuming `head` reads no further than it has to.  This works under GNU `head`.  On non-linux systems, however, one may need to check to see if the `head` command is greedy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the sed(1) route, you might want to add hexdump(1) and xxd(1) to the pipe too:

```
$>echo Hello | hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2X"' | sed 's/48656C6C6F/476F6F64627965/' | xxd -r -p
Goodbye
```